# Как отключить ключевое слово export в модулях javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, модули

Вчера попробовал новые javascript модули, я уже пользовался модулями в D и поэтому понимал что эта вещ хорошая, и плохо что в основных популярных языках С, js, C++ всегда небыло модулей.

и вобщем что меня разочаровало, да модули сейчас в js и node.js есть, но и есть ложка дёгтя в бочке с мёдом, это то что перед каждой функцией которая используется в других модулях, нужно писать слово export.

```
export function chunkArray(t){
    let tmp = new Array(t.data.length/t.width);
    for(let i = 0, k = 0; i < tmp.length; i++, k += t.width){
        tmp[i] = t.data.slice(k, k + t.width);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

"export function" это некрасиво, это слишком длинно

зачем писать перед каждой функцией export если она и так указывается в import?

```
import {chunkArray} from "./other/utils.mjs";
```

И вот у меня вопрос. Есть ли какой-то флаг может быть в Node.js или в Хроме что-то, чтобы отключить это ключевое слово export? чтобы и без нево работало? Если я так понимаю что и в хроме и в node.js обязательно, то значит это навсегда?

Comment: _Есть ли какой-то флаг может быть в Node.js или в Хроме что-то, чтобы отключить это ключевое слово export?_ -  нет

Comment: _"export function" это некрасиво, это слишком длинно_ - это позволяет разделить публичные и приватные члены модуля.

Comment: кроме того, никто не заставляет писать export перед каждой функцией, export можно написать все один раз и указать что ты экспортируешь.

Comment: если есть import * from; то почему нет export *;

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что `export *` нет? он есть, просто предназначен для другого.

Comment: а что если сделать скрипт, который бы проходил по всем файлам, собирал имена переменных и потом в конец файла записывал export {var1,var2,var3}

Comment: Можно и так, но тогда смысл модуля теряется. Намного проще сразу оформить функции как поля объекта: `var obj = { func1:function(){}, func2:function(){} ...}`  и потом просто экспортировать этот объект: `export obj;`

Comment: я написал скрипт вот смотри https://vk.com/doc96989836_466588771
теперь можно не писать везде export а просто запускать этот скрипт перед запуском программы